# WCS email sending

Tags: websphere-commerce

I'm trying to generate a mail when my process is complete in WCS, please share some links or info about how to get started. 
Like order placing I'm having a functionality for taking back few Merchendise(checking in), after this is complete, I should send an Email to specified id. I am very new to this, tried googling dint find much info. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21230937

Answer (score 0):

To send a email first of all, Enable the email transport for the site in admin console. Configure it by providing the SMTP server details.

Then you can use SendMsgCmd interface to send a email.